# custom soap authentication header creation in c# sent via iPhone

Tags: c#, web-services

Had a headace trying to get this to work,

im trying to set up my ASP.NET web service to handle a custom header sent from iPhone.

Literally, sounds simple, all I am trying to do is retrieve a string value from a header that is sent from the iPhone to the web service.

So far, the iPhone has no issues sending "test" as a value to the following header "testHeader"

in pseudo, how is it possible to

```
string s = mywebservice.soapHeader.title = "testHeader"
```

any ideas please.

I have defined my class definition for the soap header which has a string attribute, but im having no luck trying to get that string attribute the value of this custom header!

cheers in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look a this : 
[Digging into SOAP Headers with the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480503.aspx)

you should have a class in the web service that inherits **SoapHeader**

```
Public Class PriorityHeader
    Inherits SoapHeader
    Public Priority As PriorityLevels
    Public Enum PriorityLevels
        LowPriority
        MediumPriority
        HighPriority
    End Enum
End Class
```

Then markup you web method like this :

```
<WebMethod(), SoapHeader("PriorityLevel", Direction:=SoapHeaderDirection.InOut,   Required:=False),SoapDocumentMethod()>
Public Function YourMethod(ByVal quantity As Integer) As DateTime
```

And after this you can access the SOAP Header like this :

```
 If PriorityLevel Is Nothing Then
        PriorityLevel = New PriorityHeader()
        PriorityLevel.Priority = _
            PriorityHeader.PriorityLevels.MediumPriority
    End If
    Select Case PriorityLevel.Priority
    bla bla bla bla bla
```